# PL/SQL or Oracle Sql - To read specific flag that I want in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a case to read specific flags ('Y', 'N', NULL), like the condition below there are 2 conditions.

| no_contract | no_assesment | flag | value_number | Final_value_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 'Y' | 100 | 200 |
| 1 | 24 | 'N' | 200 | 200 |

| no_contract | no_assesment | flag | value_number | Final_value_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 'Y' | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 24 | NULL | 200 | 200 |

1. if the detail no_contract has flag 'N' then Final_value_number follows value_number flag 'N'
2. if the detail no_contract does not have flag 'N' then Final_value_number follows value_number for each flag itself

Comment: Could you please provide us with expected result please?

Comment: the result is on Final_value_number column

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; a larger data set than out existing 4 lines; a detailed explanation of the logic you wish to implement; and the expected output for that larger sample of data.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your "if the detail no_contract" phrase you need to decide based on partition of rows with same no_contract. Hence use window function.
For partitions without `flag='N'` the `case` expression defaults to `null` and `coalesce` applies then.

I assume the `value_number` is never null and also the `min` function is chosen randomly since you haven't specified the behaviour for two `flag='N'` rows within same `no_contract`.

```sql
with t(no_contract,     no_assesment,   flag,   value_number ) as (
select 1,   23,     'Y' ,   100 from dual union all
select 1,   24,     'N' ,   200 from dual union all
select 2,   23,     'Y' ,   100 from dual union all
select 2,   24,     NULL,   200 from dual
)
select t.*
     , coalesce(
         min(case when flag = 'N' then value_number end) over (partition by no_contract),
         value_number
       ) as Final_value_number
from t
```

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GVmMnNoi)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to self-join table if possible. My approach outer joins you table with itself filtered for 'N' columns. This might be quicker than using analytical functions or a subuery. Check the performance

```
with test_1(no_contract, no_assesment, flag, value_number) as (
  select 1, 23, 'Y', 100 from dual union all
  select 1, 24, 'N', 200 from dual union all
  select 2, 23, 'Y', 100 from dual union all
  select 2, 24, NULL, 200 from dual
)

select t1.no_contract, t1.no_assesment, t1.flag, 
       case when t1_1.no_contract is null then t1.value_number
         else t1_1.value_number
       end final_value_number
  from test_1 t1
  left join test_1 t1_1
    on t1.no_contract = t1_1.no_contract
   and t1_1.flag = 'N'
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_i-7kpg_)